# __time32_t time precision?

Tags: c++, windows, time, crt

I'm using an api which uses two __time32_t objects to open a cursor to a database, specifying the start and end time to query over.

Does __time32_t have sub-second (millisecond) time precision? The MSDN is somewhat unclear.

The time32_t object I have does this:

```
currentET-=.1;
```

Which I expected to give me the time inside of currentET minus 10 milliseconds, but all it does is subtract a full second, as if I did this:

```
currentET-=1;
```

How can I get this precision back into the time32_t object?

Answer (score 6):

`__time32_t` is just an integral type - it doesn't have any particular resolution beyond being integral. The *typical functions* `__time32_t` is used with do have 1-second resolution though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that generates a sub second accurate time output. Forgive the use of the TCHAR macros... old code base.

```
void getCurrTimeString(TCHAR* mytime)
{
    _timeb myTime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    _ftime64_s( &myTime );
    time_t rawtime = myTime.time;
    unsigned short myMillis = myTime.millitm;
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    _stprintf(mytime,_T("%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d"),
        (1900+timeinfo->tm_year),
        (timeinfo->tm_mon+1),
        timeinfo->tm_mday,
        timeinfo->tm_hour,
        timeinfo->tm_min,
        timeinfo->tm_sec,
        myMillis);
}
```

Comment: how can this be used to take in a __time32_t object?

Comment: @mattk You cannot use `__time32_t` with the required precision (open to correction on this), and `_timeb` was the only way I could see to. You should be able to substitute an existing `__time32_t` object for the `time_t rawtime` that I use. You would also need to substitute `_localtime32` for `localtime` in that case.

see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95e68951%28VS.80%29.aspx