# Is there any way to get precision time from __time32_t in c++?

Tags: c++, time, stl

I have a server where it return time in __time32_t formate I want to get time in milisecond formate from __time32_t. Is it possible?

```
localtime_s(&ptm, &close_time);
        std::wcsftime(buffer, 32, U("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"), &ptm);
        result[U("close_time")] = web::json::value::string(buffer);
```

Comment: Possibly, possibly not. It depends on the implementation. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5676894/10871073)

Answer (score 1):

`__time32_t` only contains seconds, not milliseconds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170

So no, it's not possible